# Conditionally apply string modifier method

Tags: javascript, string, lowercase

Is it possible to conditionally apply a string modifier method such as `.toLowerCase()` in a more clever method than doing:

```
const text = 'ThIs Is SoMe TeXt';
const maybeConvert = (text, toLower = false) => {
    return toLower ? text.toLowerCase() : text;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an objective and unambiguous definition of "more clever" in this case?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Could you add some context? As it stands, the code doesn't make a whole lot of sense: Why do you define `text` only to create a function that takes `text` as input?

Comment: Change the type of `text` to `let`, this way you can reassign it. With `if(toLower) text = text.ToLowerCase();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you only want to do something if condition is true and don't wanna do anything if it's false

```
  const text = 'ThIs Is SoMe TeXt';
    const maybeConvert = (text, condition) => {
     return condition  && text.toLowerCase();
    }
```

Comment: This code would actually break the OP's implementation, as it would return `false` in case condition is `false`, rather than returning the given text unmodified.